# Python Regex to find last occurence of digit

Tags: python, regex

I'm currently struggling with filtering by regex in Python. I'm executing a command via ssh and i'm catching it in stdout. All goes well here but than the difficult part comes. The output of the file loaded in stdout is the following:

> Command get executed successfully. server.jvm.memory.maxheapsize-count-count = 518979584
>
> Command get executed successfully.
>   server.jvm.memory.maxheapsize-count-count = 518979584

(this multiple times). Than I'm going to execute a regular expression:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('cat ~/Desktop/jvm.log')
result = stdout.readlines()
result = "".join(result)
print(result)
line = re.compile(r'\d+\n')
rline = "".join(line.findall(result))
print(rline)
```

the print (rline) results in

```
>> 518979584 

>> 518979584

>> 518979584
```

(also multiple times). I only want to print it once. By printing rline[0] I only get the first number of the whole digit. I thought about using $ but this doesn't help, anyone?

Comment: You could just use `rline[-1]` to get the last result.

Comment: use set : `"".join(line.findall(set(result)))`, it contains only unique values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your line :

```
rline = "".join(line.findall(result))
```

is converting the list returned form `findall` into a string which is then resulting in `rline[0]` returning the first character in the string.

simply get the element from `line.findall(result)[0]`

as shown in the example below

```
>>> d = '''
     Command get executed successfully. server.jvm.memory.maxheapsize-count-count =     518979584
... 
...     Command get executed successfully. server.jvm.memory.maxheapsize-count-count = 518979584
... '''
>>> d
'\n\n    Command get executed successfully. server.jvm.memory.maxheapsize-count-count    = 518979584\n\n    Command get executed successfully.     server.jvm.memory.maxheapsize-count-count = 518979584\n'
>>> import re
>>> line = re.compile(r'\d+\n')
>>> rline = "".join(line.findall(d))
>>> rline
'518979584\n518979584\n'
>>> line.findall(d)
['518979584\n', '518979584\n']
>>> line.findall(d)[0].strip() # strip() used to remove newline character - may not be needed
'518979584'
```

Comment: the strip was just added to remove the trailing newline character `\n` from the string. maybe misleading as that might have been introduced in my copy-paste of your string.

Answer (score 2):

Well this should give you what you want.

```
(\d+)\D*$
```

Just do a search, and this will give you the last number that occurs.

```
>>> regex = re.compile(r"(\d+)\D*$")
>>> string = "100 20gdg0 3gdfgd00gfgd 400"
>>> r = regex.search(string)
# List the groups found
>>> r.groups()
(u'400',)
```

Answer (score 0):

- It is never a good idea to mix shell and Python - when you can do all in Python (like your case)
- No need for regular expressions
- `set()` provides uniqueness

  ```
  with open(<your file name>) as in_file:
      counts = set(line.rpartition(' ')[2] for line in in_file)
  ```

Comment: is that also possible when you're doing this over SSH with paramiko? How would the script know that the file isn't on its own system?

Comment: @Nicholas , I do not know paramico, but as long as you get text output in any form with line iterator, this code will work. If paramico provides file-style iterator - this will work. If it does not - you may want to check what is more efficient - using _re_ of or iterator over splitted text.